# What driver should I install to recover 'SCardTransmit got response 0x57' error?

Tags: windows, driver, javacard, smartcard-reader

I am trying to communicate with my smart card reader under windows 10 64-bit using `GlobalPlatform pro`.
Just every command I execute returns an error like:

```
> gp.exe -l
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
Failed to communicate with card in JnaCardTerminal{scardHandle=SCardContext{cd00000100000001}, name=ACS CCID USB Reader 0}: SCardTransmit got response 0x57 (null: null)

> gp.exe --acr-list-aram
Failed to communicate with card in JnaCardTerminal{scardHandle=SCardContext{cd00000100000001}, name=ACS CCID USB Reader 0}: SCardTransmit got response 0x57 (null: null)
```

I think there is a windows driver problem. Other programs I work with are correctly using drivers installed.
What standard CCID Smart Card Reader Windows driver should be installed to recover this error?

Comment: Maybe there is a 32 / 64 bit issue? The error you are getting is not smart card specific, it's listed as system error as `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). Probably that simply means that the context has not been established though.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Thank you for your response, Marteen. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: I truly don't know, usually I'd check the registry to see how the card readers are configured. But I don't know those strings anymore KY of the top of my head.